# Error trying stores-configuration in Magento 2.1

Tags: error, configuration, stores, magento-2.1.8

> I installed Magento 2.1.8 with sample data and some components. When I
>   now want to go to Stores->Configuration I am getting this error.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:176:"Notice: Undefined index: id in` /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 59";i:1;s:5731:"#0 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php(59): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/u5964p122...', 59, Array)
#1 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php(92): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator->setElements(Array, 'default')
#2 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php(135): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getTabs()
#3 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/module-config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/AbstractConfig.php(57): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getFirstSection()
#4 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\AbstractConfig->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#6 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Config\\...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#7 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Config\\...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#10 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/var/generation/Magento/Config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#13 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#16 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#17 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#20 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#22 /home/u5964p12258/domains/finefood.club/public_html/magento21/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#23 {main}";s:3:"url";s:125:"/magento21/index.php/ovnaotqq/admin/system_config/index/key/42b27dc0e2dea01f0c5047d2d426ba6b2862c77c9be3e1240874c616c1b6edc0/";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/magento21/index.php";}
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: is it fresh installed?

Comment: Yes, installed 2.1.7.and upgraded to 2.1.8. incl sample data and some components

Comment: Hi @PeterVis did u get the solution for this?